# Getting MAC Address from known network

Tags: mac, network, wifi, mac-address

I lost my old router, and I need to know its [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), only info i got is the log of my Mac (Yosemite), i have found that with this command i got a lot of info about the preferred networks (saved networks) on my Mac.

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences KnownNetworks
```

And it outputs something like:

```
"wifi.ssid.<77696669 2d756e65>" =     {
    AutoLogin = 0;
    Captive = 0;
    ChannelHistory =         (
    );
    Closed = 0;
    CollocatedGroup =         (
    );
    Disabled = 0;
    LastConnected = "2014-09-19 19:20:23 +0000";
    Passpoint = 0;
    PossiblyHiddenNetwork = 0;
    RoamingProfileType = None;
    SPRoaming = 0;
    SSID = <77696669 2d756e65>;
    SSIDString = "heeeyomywifi";
    SecurityType = Open;
    SystemMode = 1;
    TemporarilyDisabled = 0;
};
```

But i see no MAC address :(, could this be done? or shall I search somewhere else?

Comment: please add the manufacturer and the model of your lost router

Comment: Just to make sure we are solving the right problem here: What do you need the MAC (hardware) address of your lost router for?

Comment: @patrix I need it because i want to change some parameters of my network. I cant do it manually entering directly to my router because mi ISP has blocked access to the administration panel from the LAN, nor i can access from the outside, the only way to do it is calling my ISP or accessing to my ISP auto-support web page where i can modify some parameters of my router only if i have the mac address.

Comment: @patrix, and yes i have tried many tricks like resetting my router, but when i plugin the ISP cable it loads the ISP configuration which blocks all access to common users

Answer (score 2):

Pending how long was the last connection, you could find the answer in your Console log.

I have it showing the information for last 7 days. Back to Dec 23. 2014

In Console type `MAC` in the search window.

Look for `MacAuthEvent`

In systemlog7.gz file.

EDIT:

If it is older than that:

Use Terminal and type `mdfind systemlog`

if it shows ....`PreviousSystemLogs` try that one. (highlight the find and use Reveal in Finder)

If it does not show it in Terminal then look for it in the hidden folder `/private/var/db` under .cpgz archive that you have to unpack.

Comment: LastConnected = "2014-09-19 19:20:23 +0000" :-(

Comment: YOUR time machine backup? ;-)

Comment: From what I can see the answer is correct given some constraints, most prominently the fact that the computer must have (re-)connected to the router within the last seven days. So I don't think it will solve the problem described by the OP.

Comment: I run `mdfind systemlog` on my Mac here, there are no `...PreviousSystemLogs` at all.

Comment: Nice. On Snow Leopard is appears as `kernel[0]: Auth result for: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx MAC AUTH succeeded`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but last access was much time ago :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check the arp table on your mac.  From terminal

```
arp -a
```

Comment: Arps are cached for a **very** short amount of time.

Comment: Yes, tried and only showed last 3 connections